# Ziggeo meta-profiles parameter for recording video in javascript

Tags: javascript, video, video-streaming, ziggeo-api

I've been playing around with the ziggeo API and I'm trying to attach some events for a recording.  as far as I can tell, the best way to do this is to create a div with a specific id and then create the ziggeo recorder using attribs, etc.

```
<div id="video_section"></div> 
<script>
    ZiggeoApi.Events.on("system_ready", function() {
        var recorder = new ZiggeoApi.V2.Recorder({
            element: document.getElementById("video_section"),
            attrs: {
                width: 320,
                height: 240,
                theme: "modern",
                themecolor: "red",
            }
        });

        recorder.activate();
    });
</script>
```

yet, unlike the use of the simple form `<ziggeorecorder></ziggeorecorder>` which allows the passing of a meta-profile parameter,

```
<ziggeorecorder ziggeo-theme='minimalist' ziggeo-themecolor="red" ziggeo-meta-profile='META_PROFILE_TOKEN'></ziggeorecorder>
```

when adding meta-profile in the attribs, initializing the recorder (as indicated in the API reference) results in meta-profile being misinterpreted.  when changing the attribute to meta_profile, nothing gets processed.

```
        attrs: {
            width: 320,
            height: 240,
            theme: "modern",
            themecolor: "red",
            meta_profile: 'META PROFILE ID',
        }
```

beyond that, when trying to attach the event.

```
<script>
    var element = document.getElementById('video_section');
    var embedding = ZiggeoApi.V2.Recorder.findByElement(element);
    embedding.on("submitted", function(data) {
       alert("Video " + data.video.token + " was submitted!");
    });
</script>
```

I keep getting an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of null
```

does anyone have a good grip on how to do this properly? - create a recorder, set a meta-profile, and attach an event (either submission or completion of processing) to redirect back to a root path.

Comment: Still unable to attach an event without complaints of "Cannot read property 'on' of null"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use `meta-profile` instead of `meta_profile`. You may try this code:

```
<div id="video_section"></div>
<script>
ZiggeoApi.Events.on("system_ready", function() {
    var recorder = new ZiggeoApi.V2.Recorder({
        element: document.getElementById("video_section"),
        attrs: {
            width: 320,
            height: 240,
            theme: "modern",
            themecolor: "red",
            "meta-profile":"META PROFILE ID"
        }
    });

    recorder.activate();
    recorder.on("verified", function(data){
       console.log(data);
    });
});
</script>
```

Javascript doesn't allow using `-` outside quote when defining object property (CMIIW).

Comment: placing "meta-profile" into double quotes helped, but I still can't attach to an event.

Comment: I have updated the sample to attach to `verified` event. I think they don't have `submitted` event based on this page (https://ziggeo.com/docs/sdks/javascript/browser-interaction/events#javascript-revision=stable&javascript-version=v2) that's why you don't get the event called.